# how to handle row change event of table using jquery?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I have simple HTML table having multiple rows. I want to get row that I am leaving. How to handle row leave or row change event and get id of the row that I am leaving??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your HTML? It's not clear what you mean by "row that I am leaving". Is it a mouse event you're interested in, or do you have input fields in the cells?

Comment: I have got input fields in cells and it is not mouse event.

Comment: please specify the purpose why you need to get the row, and when (if its just after you focused an input field, you have to put an handler to the mouseout event and then get his parent row)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.hover()` method, the first function is the handler of the mouse entering, the second handles the mouse leave

```
//considers all rows except the first (usually used for headers)
$("tr").not(':first').hover(
  function () {
    //handles mouseenter
  }, 
  function () {
    //handles mouseleave
  }
);
```

You can use the `$(this)` inside the handlers to refer to the current row that you're leaving / entering