# Row change event of repeater

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am using C#, ASP.net 3.5

How to capture the row change event of repeater in javascript?

Comment: row change event? I must be dreaming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no *such* event exists in `Repeater` control. Take a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx) article.

Answer (score 0):

You should bind to the change event of items in your row in javascript. The default on_change event of .net does a postback, so you can handle it server side. You can also capture the mouse hover event on the row in javascript and handle the mouseenter en mouseleave methods to update your data or something. See: [how to handle row change event of table using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290281/how-to-handle-row-change-event-of-table-using-jquery)