# Row change event in table

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Row change event of repeater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269425/row-change-event-of-repeater)

I am using Repeater control. As you know we explicitly declare the table in repeater control also it renders the table in Html. My query is- Is there any way to fire an event on change of row in table using java script?

***Edit***

I want to fire an event whenever the focus comes in another row or whenever the focus lost from current row.